# Displaying hashed content on my website

Tags: php, hash, cryptography, sha256

I have a system that currently tracks user IPs and other different unique identifiers.

On certain pages, I would like to show multiple IPs most of which belong to other users(you'll just have to trust me that it's necessary and not for a bad cause, quite the opposite). For obvious reasons I don't want to just show plaintext IPs all over the place.

So my question is: would saving said IPs as hashed content using something like sha256 be secure enough to display to other users?

I had thought about concatenating a more complex string to the beginning/end of the IP before hashing thus possibly making it more complex? I am almost certain this is very bad practice, but thoughts?

I could always make a second table in the database that links all IPs to a completely random unique identifier, however, I would prefer to avoid that and only used hashed IPs if it would be considered somewhat safe.

Comment: If you hash them, you will never know what the IP originally was. A hash is not reversable ( well it shouldn't be )

Comment: A hash will not look like an ip, so displaying it will not look like an ip

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not need to know what it originally was. Only comparing it to user input. And while they may not look like an IP, they will know that it is a hashed IP.

Comment: You won't be able to compare IPs in the same range, do you care about that?

Comment: Well you can compare an input ip with a hashed ip but in that case why not just return `yes it is` or `no it is not`

Comment: Are you using HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hashing the IPs without a salt will make it fairly easy to reverse as there are exactly 2^32 [~4 billion] possibilities to bruteforce, and that can be done surprisingly quickly these days.
2. Hashing the IPs with a global salt will likely only make them marginally more secure as all someone needs to do is find their own IP hash and bruteforce *that* to determine the salt, and then you're back to 1.
3. Hashing the IPs with a per-IP salt is where it becomes reasonably secure, but at this point you're already generating random values per-ip so you might as well just use random IDs anyway.

Comment: Hmm alright, thanks for the info. I'll probably just end up using randomly generated strings for all of them. Much appreciated.